# AngularJS greetController Controller not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm on my way in learning AngularJS, I'm following a tutorial and I found myself stuck in a point as I cannot make the `greetController` controller to work.

Here the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML.it</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="userController">
            <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.fname"></p>
            <p>Lastname: <input type="text" ng-model="user.lname"></p>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="greetController">
            <h3>{{greet()}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the app.js:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('userController', function($scope){
        $scope.user = {fname: "Joe", lname: "Black"};
    });

    app.controller('greetController', function($scope){
        $scope.greet = function () {
            return "Hi " + $scope.user.fname + ' ' + $scope.user.lname; 
        };
    });

})();
```

The result is "**{{greet()}}**" with no output.

The console says: `Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined`

I guess I have the `user.fname` not readable from the greetController, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$scope.user  user belongs to the controller named **'userController'**

Hence it is undefined in the  **'greetController'**

You may choose `$rootScope` to Declare the user as a global object or consider using **`Service`** to share variable among controller.

One simple solution would be using the same **`userController`**.

Using Single Controller [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/hwJxFX?p=preview)

Using $rootScope [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Va3CA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please show me thru code how to do it via $rootScope and how with a service? Also, which is best? Is it perhaps better to create a "globalController" and make it senior to all other controllers?

Comment: i have updated the answer , according to my knowledge i would choose the services if you are sharing the data accross various controllers, if not singler controller will be the best choice

Answer (score 1):

because $scope.user does not exist in greetController.
$scope.user is defined in userController and you're trying to access it in greetController.

in angular, each controler has its own scope and only inherits properties from its parent controller.

since greetController and userController are siblings, properties defined in one are not shared to the other

the easiest way to make the example work is to make greetController a child of userController, like so:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="userController">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.fname"></p>
        <p>Lastname: <input type="text" ng-model="user.lname"></p>
        <div ng-controller="greetController">
            <h3>{{greet()}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Otherwise, they should for an event that is listened to by a controller that contains both of them so both controllers can stay decoupled

Answer (score 0):

`greetController` needs to be a child of the `userController` controller in order this to work. So the HTML would have to be

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="userController">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.fname"></p>
        <p>Lastname: <input type="text" ng-model="user.lname"></p>

        <div ng-controller="greetController">
            <h3>{{greet()}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However this is clumsy as you can see as you need to change HTML. Proper solution is not to use dummy extra controller and use single `userController`:

```
app.controller('userController', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {fname: "Joe", lname: "Black"};

    $scope.greet = function () {
        return "Hi " + $scope.user.fname + ' ' + $scope.user.lname; 
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userController">
    <div>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.fname"></p>
        <p>Lastname: <input type="text" ng-model="user.lname"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>{{greet()}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note, that now both models `ngModel` and `{{greet()}}` are within the scope of the common `userController`.